# why is load(), on(), bind() etc on element not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net-core, razor-pages

I recently moved from WPF to Razor Pages(single page app, NOT MVC Razor Views) and I cannot access functions on an element.

in my partial view (crews.cshtml)

```
@page
@model CrewsModel
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row>">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="clickyButton">refresh</button>
            <p id="timeDisplays" class="row">                
                <partial name="Controls/DateTimeDisplayControl" , model="3/1/2019" />
            </p>
        </div>        
    </div>

</body>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
      var element = document.getElementById("timeDisplays");
      console.log(element.className);
      element.load("/DateTimeComponent?handler=DisplayTimePartial");
      console.log("Reloaded");
</script>
```

I am able to get the element.className to write out to the console.  However when i call the load (or 'on', or 'bind') function i get:

```
TypeError: element.load is not a function
```

I have also tried:

```
element.on("load","/DateTimeComponent?handler=DisplayTimePartial");
```

For a test, I replaced the body of the function with:

```
            if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined')
            {
                // jQuery is loaded => print the version
                alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
            }
```

to make sure jQuery was loaded and on the proper version.

The end goal is to reload the partial page view in the 'timeDisplays' div on demand.

I am using .net core 2.2 and jquery 3.3.1

Comment: Those methods are features of jQuery objects, not DOM elements. Instead of `getElementById()` it'd be `$("#timeDisplays)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using jQuery api load method but instead of a browser api, which doesn't have load method
So you can do like this:

```
script>
      var element = $("#timeDisplays");
      element.load("/DateTimeComponent?handler=DisplayTimePartial");
      console.log("Reloaded");
</script>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This is correct, but strictly speaking those are *browser* APIs, not JavaScript APIs. Well actually they're *not* browser APIs, which is basically the whole problem :)

Comment: THANKS! I was able to get load() working correctly, which moves on to my next problem, route path errors :)

To make sure I am clear, it was using 'document.getElementById()' instead of '$' which was causing it to execute javascript, not jQuery,.

Comment: @JoeK well jQuery *is* JavaScript.  The difference is that the browser APIs give you back direct references to DOM elements, which do have their own abilities. What jQuery does is provide *wrapper* objects that come with their own API layer that's ultimately built on the browser DOM API.